# HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized Error on curl request - heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, curl, heroku, httprequest

i'm trying to send a request via curl to my heroku based api but i keep getting this error:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 23.21.169.234...
* Connected to helphy-api.herokuapp.com (23.21.169.234) port 80 (#0)
> POST /users/sign_in HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: helphy-api.herokuapp.com
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Bearer d5bd07e4-a1c9-46d2-8d8e-d2a7cbc8501f, Accept: application/json
> Content-Length: 68
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 68 out of 68 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized 
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Content-Type: */*; charset=utf-8
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< X-Request-Id: 5b615fce-0674-4302-a9b9-f12cb00db754
< X-Runtime: 0.005328
* Server WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.0.0/2014-11-13) is not blacklisted
< Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.0.0/2014-11-13)
< Date: Fri, 16 Jan 2015 21:10:12 GMT
< Content-Length: 49
< Via: 1.1 vegur
```

This is my curl request:

```
curl -v -H "Authorization: Bearer $TUTORIAL_KEY, Accept: application/json" -X POST http://helphy-api.herokuapp.com/users/sign_in   -d '{"user": {"email": "xxxxxxx@gmail.com", "password": "xxxxxxx"}}'
```

UPDATE

this is the log:

```
2015-01-16T21:43:04.342815+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SessionsController#create as */*
2015-01-16T21:43:04.342822+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"{\"user\": {\"email\": \"xxxxxx@gmail.com\", \"password\": \"xxxxxxx\"}}"=>nil}
2015-01-16T21:43:04.347678+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 401 Unauthorized in 5ms
updating...done. Updated to 3.23.2
```

Email and password are correct and chequed, btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `-d` parameter should be x-www-form-urlencoded like a query string:

```
user[email]=email&user[password]=password
```

If you want to continue using JSON the way you are you have to add the Content-type header to your `-H`:

```
Content-type: application/json
```

This let's the server know to interpret your POST data as JSON rather than a x-www-form-urlencoded string. This is why in the server log the Parameters are coming out like:

```
Parameters: {"{\"user\": {\"email\": \"xxxxxx@gmail.com\", \"password\": \"xxxxxxx\"}}"=>nil}
```

That's just a string, not JSON because the server doesn't know you're sending it JSON because you didn't include the Content-type header and by default servers assume POST data is a x-www-form-urlencoded string.